# Visual Studio - javascript file generation almost freeze PC - how to disable

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, compilation, visual-studio-2017

right now I'm writing a code in Visual Studio 2017 (Community). 
The code is a mix of Asp.Net, C# and Javascript (with some plugins, like jQuery, knockout, etc..)
I'm facing a very frustrating thing in visual studio that is EVERY time I modify and save a single javascript file, Visual Studio starts a generation of ALL javascript files that slows down A LOT the computer (SSD, intel i5, 8gb RAM) until it finishes, sometimes I need to wait it finish to be able to continue writing my code. 
I don't know why VS do this, but I want to know if it's possible to disable it and prevent VS to generate/compile those files every time a save just one file.
Here goes an image that show what VS do:
[image]

Somebody knows what is that and what can be done to disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a similar issue, and disabling the language service seemed to help me.

Tools > Options > Text Editor > JavaScript/TypeScript > Language Service

[Disable Language Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRhlS.jpg)

Comment: Great, it really helped, now VS appears faster than before and also is showing tips for pure javascript instead of typescript. Thanks!